# Hows my symbolization for the following Argument?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

> Every philosophical empiricist admires Humes. Some philosophical idealists like no one who admires Humes. Therefore, some philosophical idealists like no philosophical empiricists.

$\forall x(Ex \implies Hx)$

$\exists x(Ix \land \forall y(Hy \implies -Lxy))$

$\therefore$ $\exists x(Ix \land \forall y(Ey \implies -Lxy))$

is this correct?

My lack of confidence stems around the conclusion, intuitively (in my mind) it reads: There is a philosophical idealist say x with that property that if y is an arbitrary philosophical empiricists then x does not like y.

However it could also read: $\exists x(Ix \land -\forall y(Ey \implies Lxy))$

I.e. There is a philosophical idealist that does not like any philosophical empiricist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Unlike in [our previous exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4674436/21813), there is no negation ambiguity here because the word "no" is firmly referring to the count of Empiricists.